# Merge two PDF's generated with jsPDF into one document

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF for generation of document from HTML (with using `.html()` method) and it works fine. But now I need to do next:

1. Create jsPDF object.
2. Add content with using `.html()` method.
3. Add new page to created document.
4. Add content to second page with using the same `.html()` method.
5. Save created document.

Here is the code example:

```
var doc = new jsPDF({ orientation: 'p', format: 'a4'  });
doc.html(document.getElementById('test'), {
   callback: function (doc) {
      doc.addPage('a4', 'p');
      doc.html(document.getElementById('test'), {
         callback: function (doc) {
            doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
      }
   }
}
```

Problem is the second page is always blank. The idea is to create two separate documents with using `.html()` method and then merge this two document into one and save it.

So question is - is it possible in jsPDF to merge two documents into one and save it then?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this feature requested [here](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/131)

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284248/generate-a-multipage-pdf-document-using-jspdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can successfully merge multi jsPDF object to one pdf file with this:

```
// .ts
 private async generatePdfList(type: string, page = 1) {
    console.log('STEP 1:', new Date());
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.staff-list-receipt');
    const elementArray = Array.from(elements);
    const bufferPromises: Promise<any>[] = elementArray
      .filter(element => !!element)
      .map(element => this.elementToPdfBuffer(type, element, page));
    const pdfArrayBuffers = await Promise.all(bufferPromises);
    console.log('STEP 2:', new Date());
    const mergedPdf = await this.mergePdfs(pdfArrayBuffers);
    const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([mergedPdf], { type: 'application/pdf' }),
    );
  }

  async elementToPdfBuffer(type, element, page) {
    // option 1:
    // const pdf: jsPDF = html2pdf().from(element).toPdf().get("pdf");
    // option 2:
    new jsPDF().fromHTML(element);
    const pdfBuffer = await pdf.output("arraybuffer");
    return pdfBuffer;
  }

  async mergePdfs(pdfsToMerges: ArrayBuffer[]) {
    const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create();
    const actions = pdfsToMerges.map(async pdfBuffer => {
      const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBuffer);
      const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdf, pdf.getPageIndices());
      copiedPages.forEach((page) => {
        // console.log('page', page.getWidth(), page.getHeight());
        page.setWidth(210);
        mergedPdf.addPage(page);
      });
    });
    await Promise.all(actions);
    const mergedPdfFile = await mergedPdf.save();
    return mergedPdfFile;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you only need merge then just use one PDF lib, no need to load both `jspdf` and `pdf-lib`, every single one is heavy enough.